# Using Lucene, Solr or elasticsearch to index Amazon S3, Rackspace Cloud Files or OpenStack SWIFT

Tags: solr, lucene, amazon-s3, elasticsearch, openstack

Has anyone used Lucene, Solr or elasticsearch to index Rackspace Cloud Files or OpenStack SWIFT (Cloud Storage)? If so what were your experiences? Any tips? What are the drawbacks?

Comment: Would probably be better being asked on here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently release an Elasticsearch connector for Amazon-S3 (see http://lbroudoux.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/indexing-your-amazon-s3-bucket-with-elasticsearch/). Though I am not using it for months ;-), it is running from other a week and has already indexed some dozeons of GB without issues !

Hope this little feedback may help ...

Regards,